# Data conversion pattern with Business Object, DTO and Entity/Domain Object

Tags: spring, design-patterns

In my Spring boot project I use hibernate and basically we have three kinds of objects

- DTO object which is used in the controller layer.
- Business Object - business object is what we use throughout our application.
- Entity/Domain Object - which is used in JPA layer.

When we are ready to save the data we turn the Business Object to Domain/Entity Obj

And when we are ready to send it to the client/controller we can convert the entity object to Business Obj and this Business object in turn to DTO Obj.

Ideally I was told that the conversion logic of changing BOs to -> (DTOs and entities) and vice versa reside in the BOs itself?

How do we achieve this in an efficient way? Can anyone help with any examples?

Answer (score 1):

I love to use [Mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) in all the projects that I am participate in

There are several things that I adore most about it:

1. Obviously, you spend less time on coding the conversions (have a look at 'MapStruct in 2 Minutes' on the main page)
2. If you the property names in your class that you want to transform to and from are the same then you write even less of code.
3. It integrates well with spring, so you don`t need to declare any beans or something, just specify that it is "spring" component model.
4. You have variety of ways how to map entities - create new, update existing with values from DTO(for example).
5. Children objects are easily mapped as well. It has internal mechanism that tries to pick up the right mapper method in other mappers. Or you can specify its name yourself arbitrary.

Though you can also have a look at [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) as well. Pretty similar library, but less used by myself. So cannot make any particular advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no silver bullet for this task, but you can consider using model mapper for that; that's the simple example https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application